# Magento coupon discount is applying twice

Tags: magento

I have set a rule which is to give $20 discount if cart subtotal is more than $100 and as my items price are mostky less than 100 obviously i am adding two product in cart or increasing the qty of same product to get subtotal more than 100. now when i apply coupon it is applying twice (i mean no of products in cart lets say 2) and giving discount of $40. any idea why?

Comment: Are you creating a catalog or a cart rule?

Comment: i am using shoping cart price rule

Comment: Have you tried stopping further processing option ?

Comment: yes i have already tried that as well.

Comment: @Nirmesh Is your issue solved?

Comment: Looks, there is no way of doing so. Anyone has found a solution yet?